# Analyse features of the connected components with histogram with opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I found many example working **histogram in opencv**, but they are **mostly working on images**.

For my case, I found each connected components in my image. From these connected components, I **calculated their area(); boundingbox(); density()**; 
**Thus, I stored value of each features (area, height and density) in each array (arr_area, arr_height, arr_density).**

I want to analyse those features in histogram

- What are the most populated area in the histogram?
- How many connected components in certain areas?
- ....

So I believe histogram can show all these information.

**How can I build these histograms in opencv c++?** 
**I.e :**

- In Histogram area : x = number of area, and y is number of cc
- In Histogram height: x = number of height, and y is number of cc
- In Histogram density: x = number of density, and y is number of cc

**Thank**

Comment: Why don't you simply count the number of connected components with a given area, height, density using a classic array of `int` ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV might not be the right tool for you to use in order to create and plot histograms. There is a tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) which talks about calculating an R,G,B histogram for an image and how to plot that using OpenCV's line function.

There are a number of of simple C++ plotting libraries that you could probably use to build the histograms (if you want to actually plot them).

If you are just looking to get a histogram of a vector of values, then you'll likely have to come up with your own binning function. The concept is fairly simple, and there are a lot of examples out there in googleland.